# Iterate a string using a for loop and accesing indexes in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to iterate a string to do an if statement to check if its uppercase or not for example:

```
s="abcd"
for x in s:
    if s[x].isupper():
        print(s[x])
```

However this doesn't work. But if I use a `while` loop, it works:

```
i=0
while i < len(s):
    if s[i].isupper():
        print(s[i])
```

I just want to know if the same `while` loop can be made with a `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because a `for` loop **iterates over the characters**. So `x` in your `for` loop is a character, **not an index**:

```
s="abcd"
for x in s:
    if x.isupper():
        print(x)
```

Should work. Python sees strings as an *ordered collection* of characters. A `for` loop over a collection usually iterates over its elements (the keys in case of a dictionary).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: well JavaScript also has the weird behavior that a `foreach` iterates over indices. I mean it does not make sense to emit indices if you feed a list. Programming language designers are simply weird people :)